# How to set Pycharm as favorite in toolbar in ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10, pycharm

I have to install Pycharm in ubuntu 18.10 but it is not lock in a favorite. So how to lock as a favorite in ubuntu 18.10?

[image: Here I attach the image for the not showing set as a favorite]

Comment: you already installed Pycharm?

Comment: How did you install pycharm? Have you downloaded a zip or umake? How do you run Pycharm? using a `.sh` file or some kind of shortcut?

Comment: this might be helpful for you [Create Launcher in Ubuntu](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205809549-Create-Launcher-in-Ubuntu-12-04-Unity-)

Comment: Yes I have installed pycharm download zip and run .sh command

Answer (score 4):

**Solution - 1**

Just run the pycharm and on the dock you'll see the pycharm icon then just right click on it and choose the **Add to Favourites**. I hope this makes clear to you

You'll See Something Like this:

[image]

**Solution - 2**

- start your pycharm through command-line like this `./pycharm.sh`
- Goto and select `Tools -> Create Desktop Entry`

**Solution - 3**

If these solutions are not working then try to install pycharm from [snap store](https://snapcraft.io/pycharm-community) it has both community and professional edition in case you have license key so that your problem will be completely solved. In order to install pycharm using snap execute the commands

For **Community** Edition:

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

For **Professional** Edition

```
sudo snap install pycharm-professional --classic
```

Happy Ubuntu!

Comment: In my case, these windows not appear it is only sawing the All Windows and Quit menu. And Also I attach my this window related in the question

Comment: I have edited my answer please try to apply the solutions, if your are having some issues regrading these solutions please comment issue

Comment: I'll rather say try Solution 2 instead of reinstalling pycharm's snap package. After creating Desktop Entry, the icon should appear in application menu from where you can right click on the icon and add to favorites

Comment: yeah but comparatively solution 3 has its own merits like it automatically updates applications and all configuration we needed it already comes with it

Comment: I have 18.04, not 18.10, but solution 2 worked for me.